# spring @Transactional rolling back halfways

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have a weird issue with @Transactional, the thing is, it's not doing a complete rollback on an error and I don't get why.

This is my service:

```
@Transactional
public class AService {

    @Autowired
    private AuditRepository auditRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RequestStatusRepository requestStatusRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ApprovementRepository approvementRepository;

    public void approve(long approvementId) {
        updateStatus();
    }

    private void updateStatus(long approvementId){
        Approvement approvement = approvementRepository.findById(approvementId);
        updateApprovement(approvement);

        Request request = requestRepository.findById(approvement.getRequest().getId());
        updateRequest(request);
    } 

    private void updateApprovement(){
        approvementRepository.save(approvement);
    }

    private void updateRequest(Request request){
        requestRepository.save(request);
        auditRepository.save(new Audit(request));
    }
}
```

This is the Approvement Repository they are all similar:

```
@Repository
public class ApprovementRepositoryImpl implements ApprovementRepository {

    @Autowired
    private JpaApprovementRepository jpaApprovementRepository;

    private Mapper mapper = DozerBeanMapperSingletonWrapper.getInstance(); 

    @Override
    public Approvement findById(long id) {
        return jpaApprovementRepository.findById(id).map(this::to).orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Approvement approvement) {
        jpaApprovementRepository.save(from(approvement));
    }

    public Approvement to(ApprovementEntity from){
        return mapper.map(from, Approvement.class);
    }

    public ApprovementEntity from(Approvement to){
        return mapper.map(from, ApprovementEntity.class);
    }
}
```

Ok, the request I'm getting has a very long field and the auditRepository isn't being able to store it, the change in audit never happened, and the change in request gets rolled back, but, the change in approvement it's being commited.

Why is this happening? I've been trying different types of propagations, and moving the @Transactional annotation from the class to the public method without success, any ideas would be great, thanks.

Comment: Which database are you using, I suspect MySQL with MyISAM tables.

Comment: yes, it´s MySql 5.7

Comment: These are not DDL querys, it still matters?

Comment: Switch to InnoDB tables instead of MyISAM tables. MyISAM doesn't support transactions, where InnoDB does.

Comment: but the engine of the tables is InnoDB, if that was the problem then the rollback wouldn't happend at all

Comment: show us the code for your repositories. are they annotated with @transactional as well? a requires_new in there somewhere? otherwise what you are describing is pretty much impossible.

Comment: Hi, there are no more @Transactional annotations around, and no requires_new propagation, I really don't see why it doesn't work either.

Comment: The rolblback isn't happening, nor is the second insertion as that fails due to a constraint violation. Have you actually **checked** that the table type is InnoDB in the database?

Comment: Yes I have checked